# Select rows matching a WHERE clause where no newer rows sharing a specific column column value exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following table called `lead_states`

It has the following columns: `id`, `lead_id`, `state`, `note`, `created_at`

`state` is a string from an enumerated list, e.g. `new`, `opened`, `sold` or `lost`.

Whenever a lead changes state, a new state row is added.

I am looking to find leads in a specific state. The current state of a lead is the newest lead_state for that lead.

So what I am basically looking to end up with a scope like:

```
Lead.in_state('opened')
```

I have tried the following implementation of that scope:

```
def in_state(state)
  lead_state_scope = LeadState.where(state: state)
  Lead.where(id: lead_state_scope.select(:lead_id))
end
```

However, this will return all leads that at some point in their lifecycle has been in the state queried for.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you break this up however you would like to in the method but this should get you exactly what you need. Adding the group and having method to the inner query solves your lead lifecycle problem because it get's the latest state of the lead.

```
def in_state(state)
    Lead.where(id: LeadState.where(state:state).group(:lead_id).having('created_at = MAX(created_at)').select(:lead_id))
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but Postgres chokes on the resulting query.

SELECT "lead_states"."lead_id" FROM "lead_states" WHERE "lead_states"."state" = 'opened' GROUP BY "lead_states"."lead_id" HAVING created_at = MAX(created_at)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "lead_states.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: try adding `.select(:lead_id, :created_at)` in between the where clause and the group clause, see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Aha, yeah this definitely seems to be be Postgres specific depending on your version https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1515. My answer could be helpful for others but I need to think a bit more on what can be done for your situation.